# Given G an Undirected Graph with > 3 Vertices(V). Prove that V Can Always be of 3 Colors Such that at Least 2/3 Edges don't Connect V of Same Color

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Let $G$ be an undirected graph with $n>3$ vertices and $m$ edges.
$\text{Edges} = \{ (i_{i} < j_{i}), \dots, (i_{m} < j_{m}) \}.$ Prove that we can always color vertices in 3 colors such that at least $ \dfrac{2}{3} m $ edges don't connect vertices of the same color.

---

I see the same $\dfrac{2}{3}$m edges equation [here](http://web.math.princeton.edu/math_alive/5/Notes2.pdf) in page 21 and point 6. It's under the theorem that shows that every planar graph has at least one vertex of degree 5 or less.

However, I still do not see the connection to this problem and do not know how to proceed. What if my number of edges is not divisible by 3? I would get a fraction for the at least statement. What does that even mean? 
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color the vertices with three colors at random.

Then for each edge, the probability that that edge connects two vertices of the same color is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{3}$.  By linearity of expectation, the expected number of edges which connect vertices of the same color is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{3}m$; that is, the expected number of edges that do not connect vertices of the same color is $\displaystyle \frac{2}{3}m$.

This means that the average, over all colorings of the graph with three colors, of the total number of edges that do not connect vertices of the same color is $\displaystyle \frac{2}{3} m$.  Therefore, there must be some coloring for which the number of such edges is at least $\displaystyle \frac{2}{3} m$.

Comment: On your last paragraph, by "over all colorings" you mean 3?

Comment: @user2227735 I am sure he means "over all 3-colorings"

Comment: All 3-colorings of the graph (there are $3^n$ of them; we analyzed what happens when you choose one at random in the first part).  Perhaps I should edit to make this clear.

Comment: Also on the last statement, "there must be some coloring for which the number of such edges is at least $2/3$ m"; you mean that at least for one of these 3 colors, the vertex has $2/3$ m edges that do not connect the same vertex-color? I think I got it. Thank you.

Comment: A "coloring" refers to some way of giving a color (in this case one of three colors) to *every* vertex in the graph.  So this just says that there is some way of giving a color to every vertex in the graph so that at least $\frac{2}{3}m$ of the edges in the graph connect vertices that were given different colors.